# jQuery Portlet/Sortable - Stop reloading data on portlet move

Tags: jquery, drag-and-drop, portlet

I am using jQuery portlets but have run into an issue. When I move an item (changing its position on the page) its contents are automatically reloaded, causing excessive database calls and other confusion. I can't seem to figure out where these calls are originating or if there is a way to disable this behavior.

Any help would be greatly appreciated,

Thanks

JP

Answer (score 0):

This is part of the standard portlet lifecycle RENDER phase. How to prevent it from happening will largely depend on the framework that you're using, but in short you need to check to see if you're getting a render or action request and only perform the re-lookups based upon that state.